# Strange FROM value in W output of Linux

Tags: linux

I ran `w` command to see who is logged in on a server.

I am getting the following:

```
root@server:/var/www/# w
 13:50:33 up 881 days, 17:24,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
agc      pts/0    :1009.0          29Jun11 708days  0.12s  0.12s bash
root     pts/1    pcait191.menios.gr 13:45    0.00s  0.06s  0.01s w
```

How do I interpret `:1009.0` in from column?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w` uses this to show logins from an X server. It follows the naming scheme of X displays (see `man 7 X`, 'DISPLAY NAMES')

```
[hostname]:<displaynumber>[.screennumber]
```

- The missing hostname indicates that the X server runs on the local machine.
- '1009' is just the number of of the display (from `man X 7`: " "display" is usually used to refer to a collection of monitors that share a common set of input devices". Usually it is '0' for the first display of a machine, '1' for the second and so on. But the numbers can be arbitrarily chosen (so there may not be 1009 other displays). Note that there can be several displays even if there is only one set of monitors and input devices, just like there can be more then one console terminal.
- '.0' would be the first screen (on newer systems multiple monitors are often combined to one virtual screen, so values other than '0' are not that common any more)